# Unable to find who made changes to file

Tags: linux

In linux, I have a file which is modified by someone and we are trying to track down - can you please tell which is the best way to find out how it modified . But the point is account name which we used to login is same for all. lets say test account.

Thanks

Comment: Sharing accounts isn't a good idea, but you figured that out by now. If you have SSH logins, then try looking in `/var/log` for the IP address of the login at the time of the file modification. That is, provided your SSH daemon logs this, provided that the log file isn't rotated away by now, ... Lots of degrees of freedom.

Comment: i see nothing in ssh logs or secure logs - still any log file there to check ?

Comment: You might check `~/.bash_history` for what that user might've done besides changing the file, might give you a hint to their identity. It's a long shot and other than that, I'm out of ideas... good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only way to find out is bash_history